# How to use hasManyRadioButton() in cfwheels?

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

The cfwheels documentation says that for using hasManyRadioButton() the property field is required. But in their example they haven't used property.

Following is the [example](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/function/hasManyRadioButton) provided by cfwheels documentation.

```
<!--- Show radio buttons for associating a default address with the current author --->
<cfloop query="addresses">
    #hasManyRadioButton(
        label=addresses.title,
        objectName="author",
        association="authorsDefaultAddresses",
        keys="#author.key()#,#addresses.id#"
    )#
</cfloop>
```

Is the property attribute required or not? What is the right convention to use this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the `property` argument would be required. The example appears to be incomplete.

The docs should probably look something like this:

```
<!--- Show radio buttons for associating a default address with the current author --->
<cfloop query="addresses">
    #hasManyRadioButton(
        label=addresses.title,
        objectName="author",
        association="authorAddresses",
        keys="#author.key()#,#addresses.id#",
        property="isDefault",
        tagValue=true
    )#
</cfloop>
```

Note that I changed the `association` argument to show that it probably intended to be a join table linking `author` with `address`. I also added `property` and `tagValue` arguments as well.

In this case, the radio button is setting some value on the child object (in this example, the `authorAddress` model).